# data not insert into database in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

Trying to insert data in database from edittext in android
but data is not inserting.

MY CODE --

```
ContentValues values= new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_EMAIL, GlobalVar.email);
values.put(KEY_NAME, GlobalVar.name);
myDataBase.insert(MY_EMP, null,values);
```

MY LOG CAT

```
04-10 09:50:20.121: E/running(280): create database called
04-10 09:50:20.121: E/running(280): chek database called
04-10 09:50:20.121: E/running(280): chek database try block called
04-10 09:50:20.171: E/running(280): create database called try block
04-10 09:50:20.191: E/running(280): copy database called
04-10 09:50:20.211: E/running(280): open data successfull
04-10 09:50:50.720: W/KeyCharacterMap(280): No keyboard for id 0
04-10 09:50:50.720: W/KeyCharacterMap(280): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

`

Comment: It seems that you're missing the relevant log output because there's no stack trace. Is this code throwing an exception?

Comment: please provide some more information from your log file like @Tyler Treat mentioned.

Comment: How can you say data not inserted in SQLite..have you checked the database from data folder in any SQLite browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't supply all the required column data (i.e. data for all columns that don't have a default value, accept null, or are auto-incrementing), then the insert command will fail.

However, if `insert` fails, it doesn't throw an exception. It just returns -1.

Check the result of your `insert` call, or better yet, change the call to

```
myDataBase.insertOrThrow(MY_EMP, null,values);
```

and then check the logs for the exception message assuming there is one.

Answer (score 1):

It seems u r missing the required parameters in myDataBase.insert(MY_EMP, null,values);
it should be myDataBase.insert("Table Name ", "First column name ",cv);

Try this

Comment: This is not necessarily correct. The second parameter is the null column hack (and it's certainly not required), so unless he's inserting a completely empty row, which I don't think he is, this is wrong.